# Azure ad: invitation to external guest fails

Tags: email, azure-activedirectory

I'm managing an Office 365 tenant, corporate users are managed by our IDM system, but we need to manually invite external contributors to specific SharePoint sites and teams.

I'm adding a user as guest, the email address does not belong to a differant tenant but is completely unrelated to any Microsoft cloud offerings.

The users receives the inviation and clicks the included link. A website opens which starts with https://b2b.azure.net/signup but returns 404.

Guest inviation is allowed for selected users only, I'm one of them and the invitation is sent, so that should not be an issue.

Is there anything I could have done wrong to cause an 404?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved, after several hours the link finally worked.
I guess Azure has just trouble coping with demand, there were no configuration changes on our tenant.